# asp.net mvc4 mysql error There is no 'db'@'host' registered

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

an ASP.Net mvc 4 application has been running fine (and is still running fine for some parts).

suddenly an error has started showing up : `There is no 'dbname'@'host' registered` ..

have asked person incharge of servers and they said that no ip change has occurred for the last 6 months.

currently am not aware where exactly to look in order to resolve the error (either in code or server configurations).

the connection string in web.config is as follows:

`<add name="name"
          connectionString="Server=localhost;Port=3307;Database=db;Uid=uid;Pwd=pwd;charset=utf8;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>`

any help appreciated.

Comment: It's not "dbname@host" but "username@host". Either a user got removed, or a stored procedure for a certain user was updated with a non-existing user.

Comment: @CodeCaster thank you for the reply. means that we need to add the user with the name shown in error and it should hopefully fix the issue ?

Comment: I don't like the shotgun approach and I don't like hoping some change works without knowing why that change should be made, but yeah, you could give it a try. I'd rather first get it very clear why the error occurred in the first place. Searching the web for `mysql "there is no" username @ host "registered"` points towards replication and triggers. Do you use those? Or did someone do some user management and remove a user that was still used in some code?

Comment: its a simple db so replication/triggers may not be in use. however cannot say much of user management. :) . will try and try to respond back  . thank you for your help .

Comment: @CodeCaster creating a user seemed to solve the problem . if you like, please post this as an answer so that it may be marked as answer.